# Is it possible to use 'as' keyword with procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hey guys i have made a procedure in mysql and i was wondering if can use the `as` keyword before the `begin` statement

my code

```
create procedure avinash (in hon int)
as alias
begin
select * from customers;
end//
```

When i use error i get an error and when i removed `as` keyword it worked just fine.

Is there any option where i can use `as` keyword` ..Am just asking if there is any option available in mysql.

Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

If your intent to use `as` to define an alias for the stored procedure to be able to call it as `call alias` then the answer is no. You can not use `as` in this way. The syntax for `create procedure` does not allow it.

You could create another procedure with the alias name that calls the first (but what would be the point?).